# Blazor: Test against IJSRuntime and javascript framework, not mocked, and no UI. Or, how to run JS outside of browser

Tags: c#, indexeddb, blazor-webassembly, blazor-jsinterop

#### Context

I'm writing a Blazor WASM application that stores data client-side via [Blazor.IndexedDB](https://github.com/wtulloch/Blazor.IndexedDB).

I'd like to test the service that manages this data store, and I want to test against the actual IndexedDB framework. I've struggled with it silently failing. However, this framework relies on `IJSRuntime` and a javascript library.

#### Core Question

So, how can I run tests that

- Depend on javascript
- Are not part of the UI and should not be exposed to public navigation

Is there any way an IJSRuntime can run in a non-browser environment?

#### Exploration

So far I've explored

- *Searching for test suggestions*: Searching has mostly led me to ways to mock `IJSRuntime`, but mocking the javascript will render the tests meaningless.

  - Another recommendation was e2e test frameworks like [playwright](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/), but what I'm testing does not have any visual component. It's a service that happens to save client-side via js interop
- *Inspect libraries*: I've looked at several open source Blazor libraries that interop with Javascript. None that I investigated tested that interop
- *JSRuntime Instances*: I've searched for concrete implementations of JSRuntime. The closest I've found is [WebAssemblyJSRuntime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.webassembly.webassemblyjsruntime?view=aspnetcore-6.0), which is abstract but doesn't require any implementation by derivatives. Creating a derivative and running `jsruntime.InvokeAsync<int>("() => 5 + 2")` errors (error below)
- *Get JSRuntimeInstance from WebAssemblyHost*: Trying to create a WebAssemblyHost produces the same error as trying to call `jsRuntime.InvokeAsync`

Error (from JSRuntime or WebAssemblyHost)

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'WebAssembly.JSInterop.JSCallInfo' from assembly 'Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly, Version=6.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' because it contains an object field at offset 4 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field.'

I'm guessing the underlying issue is absence of a proper environment to run javascript.

Comment: i'd recommend looking into runnable browser engines like cefsharp or electron or something of that direction if you really need that, cause you are not going to be able to run blazor in just some random JS environment